# CSS doesn't change the ul

Tags: html, css

I have this block of code in HTML ,and I want to change the list to be display inline and has no bullets.

```css
#highlight ul {
  background-color: black;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<section id="highlight">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="slide-text">

        <h1></h1>
        <p></p>
        <p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

But it doesn't change anything. Do you know why?

I tried to change the code as you told me but nothing seems to work, maybe its not the code but something else

Answer (score 4):

Remove `display: inline;` in your `ul` and add it to your `li`

```
#highlight ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```css
#highlight ul {
  background-color: black;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;  
}

#highlight ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<section id="highlight">
<div class="slide">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="slide-text">

        <h1>Δρ. Παναγιώτης Νομικός <span>Νευροχειρουργός</span></h1>
        <p>Περιηγηθείτε στις σελίδες και ενημερωθείτε για θέματα νευροχειρουργικής.</p>
        <p>Για οποιεσδήποτε απορίες σας περιμένουμε να επικοινωνήσετε  μαζί μας.</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">ΠΕΡΙΣΣΟΤΕΡΑ --></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ΕΠΙΚΟΙΝΩΝΙΑ --></a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you set inline on the li rather than the ul

```
#highlight ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

This should also make the list-style propery redundant.
display: inline-block will achieve the same result and will give you some more layout control.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block;` on `#highlight ul li` and remove `display: inline;` from `#highlight ul`

Something like this:

```
#highlight ul {
  background-color: black;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#highlight ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}
#highlight ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

See the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NfeVh/1400/

Comment: none of this works, maybe its not the code but something else

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
#highlight ul {
  background-color: black;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}
#highlight ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section id="highlight">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="slide-text">

        <h1>Δρ. Παναγιώτης Νομικός <span>Νευροχειρουργός</span></h1>
        <p>Περιηγηθείτε στις σελίδες και ενημερωθείτε για θέματα νευροχειρουργικής.</p>
        <p>Για οποιεσδήποτε απορίες σας περιμένουμε να επικοινωνήσετε μαζί μας.</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">ΠΕΡΙΣΣΟΤΕΡΑ --></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">ΕΠΙΚΟΙΝΩΝΙΑ --></a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#highlight ul {
  background-color: black;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}

#highlight ul li{
  width: 30%;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="highlight">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="slide-text">

        <h1>Δρ. Παναγιώτης Νομικός <span>Νευροχειρουργός</span></h1>
        <p>Περιηγηθείτε στις σελίδες και ενημερωθείτε για θέματα νευροχειρουργικής.</p>
        <p>Για οποιεσδήποτε απορίες σας περιμένουμε να επικοινωνήσετε μαζί μας.</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">ΠΕΡΙΣΣΟΤΕΡΑ --></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">ΕΠΙΚΟΙΝΩΝΙΑ --></a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```